# jQuery remove multiple styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set all my css to null with the use of jQuery. 
I know you can do it like

```
$("[class^=col-]").css('width', '');
$("[class^=col-]").css('right', '');
$("[class^=col-]").css('margin', '');
$("[class^=col-]").css('position', '');
```

but is it possible to do it in one command, like:

```
$("[class^=col-]").css('');
```

**Edit:** i have looked in the post above and saw the answer.

By removing the style atrribute it works perfectly `$("[class^=col-]").removeAttr("style")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the default values for those properties to override the values you have set

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[class^=col-]").css({
    'width': 'auto',
    'position': 'inherit',
    'margin': '0',
    'right': '0'
  });
});
```

```css
.col-md-12 {
  width: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">some test</div>
```

Comment: It will not remove anything. Read the docs.

Comment: this does not remove every css attr that i have set

Comment: @SalmanA it does now